# VLC does not launch after installing a new skin (upgraded to 14.04 LTS)

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, vlc

After upgrade to ubuntu 14.04, VLC worked. After installing a new skin for vlc, vlc won't launch.

The skin file was deleted.
VLC was removed completely with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc*
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc-data
```

After reinstalling with synaptic vlc does not launch.

After purging vlc again, the terminal responds to: `vlc` with;

```
The program 'vlc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install vlc-nox
```

Vlc was installed with sudo apt-get install vlc-nox

Running vlc from the terminal gives:

```
VLC media player 2.1.2 Rincewind (revision 2.1.2-0-ga4c4876)
[0x1d034c8] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x1ce7058] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
```

NB: in all instances vlc 2.1.2-2build2 was installed but not working. `apt-get` was also cleaned, after purge, `sudo apt-get autoremove` removed all packages that were not needed anymore.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

No extra PPA's are present.

How to install a regular GUI version vlc?

1) To answer AzkerM VLC was installed with synaptic.

```
~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep "vlc"
libvlc5                 install
libvlccore7             install
vlc                     install
vlc-data                install
vlc-nox                 install
vlc-plugin-notify       install
vlc-plugin-pulse        install
```

2) To answer Jos:

```
    vlc --ignore-config
    VLC media player 2.1.2 Rincewind (revision 2.1.2-0-ga4c4876)
    [0xbb7058] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
    Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
    Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
    Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
    Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
[0x7fe8113cbbb8] main vout display error: Failed to resize display
```

Despite the warnings, vlc --ignore-config launched a working VLC! The old config must have been the cause of problems. vlc --reset-config is a permanent solution.
Thank you for taking an interest in this question (and for editing it).

Comment: Hi, could you please post the output for `dpkg --get-selections | grep "vlc"` by [**editing**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/462872/edit) your question. Or maybe try `vlc --reset-config` if you don't have any customized configs or anything stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing your VLC config folder `~/.config/vlc`. Or try `vlc --ignore-config`.